# Hiding elements with CSS only

Tags: programming-puzzle, css

In the following markup without changing it or using JS, implement the behavior to show only the `ul` element of `div` which name is clicked in the first `ul` (before `div`). Name is content of `li` in top `ul` and it matches the content of the first `li` in `ul` you want to show. Elements that have `{content}` are just fillers and have no meaning for problem.

```
<ul>
  <li class="head"><a href="#favorites">Favourite dishes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#breakfasts"><i>Breakfasts</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#dinners"><i>Dinners</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#suppers"><i>Suppers</i></a></li>
</ul>
<div>
    <ul id="breakfasts">
       <li class="head">Breakfasts</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 1}</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 2}</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="dinners">
       <li class="head">Dinners</li>
       <li>{Dinner 1}</li>
       <li>{Dinner 2}</li>
       <li>{Dinner 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="suppers">
       <li class="head">Dinners</li>
       <li>{Supper 1}</li>
       <li>{Supper 2}</li>
       <li>{Supper 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="favorites">
       <li class="head">Favourites</li>
       <li>{Favourite 1}</li>
       <li>{Favourite 2}</li>
       <li>{Favourite 3}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This problem really has the solution and was very interesting for me, so I decided to post it here even if it's not very practical.
Hint: you have to use `:target` pseudo-class.

Comment: Note, I don't believe this is off-topic, as it looks like a [tag:programming-puzzle] to me

Comment: @NathanMerill Programming puzzle or not, it still needs an objective winning criterion.

Comment: @Dennis isn't it first posted by default?

Comment: @NathanMerrill Amended: first _corrected_ posted

Comment: @NathanMerrill As far as I know, no. The tag doesn't even have a wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I think your hint gave too much away:

```
div>ul:target{
   display: block;
}
div>ul{
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for proposing a solution, it's almost it, but if I click the "Favourite dishes", nothing is shown